# addError is not showing anything on Lightning task page?

Tags: apex, lightning, adderror

We have code that adds error messages to objects, and the point is to do so regardless of being in classic or lightning, so addError was used.

All we are doing is this:

```
if(validationMessage!=''){
    validationMessage = (currentObj.Field_Validation_Message__c!=null ? currentObj.Field_Validation_Message__c :System.Label.Validation_Cannot_Complete__Error);
    UpdatedObj[newLoop].addError(validationMessage);
}
```

UpdatedObj is an array of objects being updated. In my particular case, it is just one Task, so `UpdatedObj[newLoop]` is just a Task.

I get the correct behavior of not actually updating, but I get no error messages on the Task page in Lightning. I am 100% positive that there is actually a validationMessage, so it is going into that if statement and adding the error (system.debugs in console, and the fact it isn't actually updating).

But I cannot figure out why the error message is nowhere to be seen on the Task lightning page. (which is just the standard task page).

Does anyone know if anything has changed with addError and lightning pages recently? Because this did work, I remember seeing the errors during testing a little while ago, and now I do not see anything.

Comment: Is `UpdatedObj` the object instances contained in Trigger.new? Otherwise (e.g. if they're queried) addError does nothing.

Comment: Hmm that maybe it. It may not be since the component updating is not the task. That could be the culprit. I'll have to look into that